# Android NDK: Static compilation with CLang error

Tags: android, android-ndk, clang

I'm currently developing a C/C++ module for an Android application using the NDK and JNI.

I need to compile this C module with CLang and use static linking in order to remove dependencies to libc.

The compilation with static linking to libC works fine with GCC but I can't get it working with CLang. I get the following error:

`D:/tools/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/lib/../lib\crtbegin_static.o:crtbrand.c:function _start: error: undefined reference to 'main'`

The example below is on Windows, but the problem is the same on linux.

To demonstrate the problem with a very simple hello world:

hello-jni.c:

```
#include <jni.h>
jstring Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz) {
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "hello world");
}
```

The makefile android.mk is:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

ifndef NDK_PATH
    NDK_PATH = C:/dev/android-ndk-r10d/
endif

SDK_VERSION = 21

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := LibC 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(NDK_PATH)platforms/android-$(SDK_VERSION)/arch- $(TARGET_ARCH)/usr/lib/libc.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libhello
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.c

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := LibC 
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -nostdlib
LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -static -v

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and  the application.mk:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang3.5
```

If it can be of any use, setting the -v flag for the LDFLAGS gives me:

`"D:/tools/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld.exe" --sysroot=D:/tools/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-21/arch-arm -X -m armelf_linux_eabi -Bstatic -dynamic-linker /system/bin/linker -o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libhello.so "D:/tools/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/lib/../lib\\crtbegin_static.o" -LD:/tools/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8 -LD:/tools/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/lib/../lib -LD:/tools/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/lib/../lib -LD:/tools/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/../../lib-LD:/tools/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/lib -LD:/tools/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/lib -soname libhello.so ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/hello/hello-jni.o D:/tools/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/lib/libc.a -lgcc --fix-cortex-a8 --no-undefined -z noexecstack -z relro -z now -lc -lm -lstdc++ -lm --start-group -lgcc -lc --end-group "D:/tools/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/lib/../lib\\crtend_so.o"
D:/tools/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/lib/../lib\crtbegin_static.o:crtbrand.c:function _start: error: undefined reference to 'main'
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libhello.so] Error 1`

If any of you could help me, I would be very grateful !

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you are trying to build a shared library `libhello.so`.

To build a shared library you must pass option `-shared` to the linker (`ld`).
Your link command shows that tyou are not doing so.
If you don't, the linker assumes you are trying to build an executable program. And you
if are trying to build a C executable, then it must have a `main` function
`int main(int argc, char *argv[])` where execution will start. If you don't,
then you will get the linkage error you are seeing. `hello-jni.c` does
not contain any `main` function, because it's supposed to be built as a library,
not a program.

So change your `LOCAL_LDFLAGS` to `-shared -static`. (Or probably more in line with
the organisation of your build, add `-shared` to the linker flags wherever they
are set within `include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)`). You
may suppose that `-shared` and `-static` are contradictory options, but they're not.
`-shared` means *build a shared library* and `-static` means *don't link any shared libraries with
whatever is being built*.

Futhermore, if you are building a shared library, then you must pass option `-fPIC`,
to generate position-independant object code, when you *compile* the source files.
We can't see any of your compile commands, but you will need `-fPIC` to be present
in the `CFLAGS` that you pass to the compiler. As far as we can see from your
makefile, you are only passing `-nostdlib`

It is unclear to me why you are passing `-nostlib` to the compiler. It is a linker
option, with no effect on compilation, and we do not see it in your link command,
where it would have some effect.

Incidentally, there appears to be a missing space lurking somewhere in
the unseen anatomy of your build. In that verbose link command, the monster `-L`
option:

```
-LD:/tools/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/../../lib-LD:/tools/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/lib
```

is clearly two joined together:

```
-LD:/tools/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/../../lib
-LD:/tools/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/lib
```

I would expect this to make the linker try to search in the monster non-existent path instead
of two shorter paths, but possibly the concatenation is just a typographical error.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for this very detailed response.
I did try to add the -fPIC flag  and remove -nostdlib from the LOCAL_CFLAGS. I also added the –shared flag to the linker but I still get the same error.
For the …lib–LD:/tools… concatenation, it’s a copy-paste issue, not an actual problem.
 
What NDK build toolchain actually does is quite unclear to me, but passing only the –static does build a .so with GCC, and that .so actually works with my Java program.
Do you suggest that would in fact be GCC that behaves oddly by doing the job rather than CLang by not doing it?